# Message app uninstalled after using viber?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-note-3, viber-messenger

I could only text people using viber, which is not usefull for out of internet zones. I uninstalled viber thinking it was a default thing. My samsung Galaxy Note 3 has uninstalled the texting application. I have since deleted viber and cannot text anyone, how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

"just solved the issue. apparently when an app is 'disabled' it ends up at the bottom of the HUGE list under application manager -> all apps

when you 'enable' the app, it re-joins it's place in the ranks alphabetically"

found this on another site,
for me it was in the tab "disabled apps"